# Как найти работу Junior?

Tags: java, android, mobile-development, работа

помогите советом.
Я Junior Android Developer. Студент программист, Минск, имею 7 месяцев опыта работы в стартапе, СЕО сказал, что выхожу на Мидла, разрабатывала CRM приложение с нуля до 2 версии, в одиночку. Также есть 8 собственных, хороших проектов с использованием машинного обучения, дополненной реальности, со всякими API, фреймворками и библиотеками.
Английский - Upper-intermediate 
Немецкий - свободный

Но на работу никто не берет, даже на курсы от компаний! Хотя технические специалисты говорили, что будут меня рекомендовать и тд. и тп., мол видят мотивацию, но приходит в итоге отказ, иногда даже на собеседование не приглашают, даже самые плохие компании.

В чем дело? Я очень хочу работать, но чувствую, что я уже угасаю, подумываю пойти продавцом работать...я вижу, что берут на работу людей с 0 знаниями, без английского, а меня нет. Я не знаю, что делать...... я бы хоть бесплатно пошла работать. У меня ни связей, ни знакомых, которые могли бы меня устроить нет.

Можете дать совет пожалуйста?

Comment: https://jobs.tut.by/search/vacancy?clusters=true&area=1002&specialization=1.221&enable_snippets=true&salary=&st=searchVacancy&text=Junior

Comment: Искать причину, почему не берут (может с вами что не так или с компаниями, куда вы хотите) -> устранять причину -> Пробоваться ещё -> В случае неудачи вернуться к началу списка.

Comment: Разве тут задают вопросы насчет работы?

Comment: @Struckture нет, потому скоро вопрос закроют

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Совет - не сдаваться. Никто не обязан брать тебя, поэтому, если отправлять письма каждый день, сотням компаниям в месяц, то рано или поздно кто-то скажет "Да".

Comment: главное не отправлять сотни писем в одну и ту же команию! ;)